# Does drinking hot beverages on a hot day make a person feel cooler?

Tags: psychology, weather, drink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is drinking hot water more beneficial during hot weather?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/is-drinking-hot-water-more-beneficial-during-hot-weather)

Over the years I've heard from various people that drinking hot beverages on a hot day will make you feel cooler.  For instance, in this [clip from the TV series *Cheers* Cliff Clavin explains the theory to Diane Chambers](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=k6GTZrcoWEM&vq=medium) when she asks about drinking cold beverages on a cold day.

There are a few related questions:

1. Does drinking hot beverages on a hot day cool a body faster?
2. Does drinking hot beverages on a hot day make a person *feel* cooler?
3. Does drinking cold beverages on a cold day heat a body faster?
4. Does drinking cold beverages on a cold day make a person *feel* warmer?

([A related question on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/is-drinking-hot-water-more-beneficial-during-hot-weather) addresses drinking cold beverages on a cold day as a method of weight loss, but does not address the question of making a person *feeling* warmer or colder.)

Comment: You are using *CLIFF CLAVIN* as a source! ROFL. Cheers writer Ken Levine has written about the [fact-checking  involved in Cliff's dialogue](http://kenlevine.blogspot.com/2009/05/cliff-clavin-explains-yorkshire-pudding.html).

Comment: @Oddthinking:  I had heard the "hot drink on a hot day" claim long before *Cheers* used it as a *Clavinism*. That being said, Skeptics.SE asks that questions be about documented claims, and the *Cheers* clip is a much better document than me quoting my old Aunt Gertie.  Besides, Cliff Clavin is hilarious! (We could probably have a separate branch within Skeptics.SE just for him.)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "feel cooler". Can it be changed to something non-subjective?