# Does a hot beverage cool you down in summer?

Tags: nutrition, natural-remedies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is drinking hot water more beneficial during hot weather?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/is-drinking-hot-water-more-beneficial-during-hot-weather)

There are many people who claim that they like to drink hot drinks during warm or hot weather, as it cools them down.

Examples of such claims are [here](http://www.sciencebase.com/science-blog/a-cooling-hot-drink.html) and [here](http://www.virtualcountries.com/forums/showthread.php?p=78164).

Is there any evidence to support this claim, or is there an alternative explanation?

Comment: Hi stp30, I edited your question to make it easier to answer, feel free to revert if you don't like the edit.

Comment: __Possible Duplicate__: [Is drinking hot water more beneficial during hot weather?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/is-drinking-hot-water-more-beneficial-during-hot-weather); [Does drinking hot beverages on a hot day make a person feel cooler?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/does-drinking-hot-beverages-on-a-hot-day-make-a-person-feel-cooler)

Comment: I've voted to close now, as the question is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @Chad I didn't think the science blog was authoritative enough for an answer.